# How to access Ubuntu var/www using nginx server

Tags: networking, system, browser, phppgadmin

I have problem here. I want to try access through browser and use http://localhost/phppgadmin to access phppgadmin but the result of that is:

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx
```

I sure phppgadmin is exist in `var/www`. How to fix it?

Comment: View the logs (nginx and php). Can't tell anything for sure from this error message alone. And does a simple "hello world" php file work in the root directory?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess I will say that maybe you're trying to use php-fpm and it's not currently running, so nginx can't connect to the socket.

try this and then restart nginx

```
sudo apt install php-fpm
```